# ContentDialog - What to Use For SecondaryButtonCommand

Tags: winui-3, icommand, contentdialog

I am creating a general purpose Exception message dialog, and want to have a "Copy Error" button to copy the error text to the clipboard.  I cannot figure out what to use for SecondaryButtonCommand = ICommand.

All my research about implementing ICommand with WinUI 3 ends up on some variation of RelayCommand and MVVM Toolkit, which I could not get to work.

I got the Copy to Clipboard to work.  I now want that to happen when user clicks a button on the dialog.

Note this dialog is created in its own class in code, and is intended to be used from any page.

What do I use for SecondaryButtonCommand = ???

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;

namespace JimPrototypes2.Helpers
{
   public static class ErrorDialog 
    {
         public static void Show(XamlRoot root,  string message, string stackTrace)
        {
            string msg = message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + stackTrace;
   
            ContentDialog err = new ContentDialog()
            {
                XamlRoot = root,
                Title = "An Error Has Occured",
                Content = msg,
                CloseButtonText = "Ok",
                SecondaryButtonText = "Copy Error",
                SecondaryButtonCommand = ???????      
            };

            err.ShowAsync();

            // Just testing copy to clipboard
            DataPackage package = new DataPackage();
            package.SetText(msg);
            Clipboard.SetContent(package);
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually came across an ICommand example that helped.  Turns out it is REALLY easy once I saw a simple, functional example.

Here is my ICommand named CopyCommand

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;

namespace JimPrototypes2.Helpers
{
    class CopyCommand : ICommand
    {
        string _copyText;

        public CopyCommand(string input)
        {
            _copyText = input;
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            DataPackage package = new DataPackage();
            package.SetText(_copyText);
            Clipboard.SetContent(package);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}
```

My updated ErrorDialog class

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;

namespace JimPrototypes2.Helpers
{
   public static class ErrorDialog 
    {
         public static void Show(XamlRoot root,  string message, string stackTrace)
        {
            string msg = message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + stackTrace;

            CopyCommand cmd = new CopyCommand(msg);

            ContentDialog err = new ContentDialog()
            {
                XamlRoot = root,
                Title = "An Error Has Occured",
                Content = msg,
                CloseButtonText = "Ok",
                SecondaryButtonText = "Copy Error",
                SecondaryButtonCommand = cmd      
            };

            err.ShowAsync();
        }      
    }
}
```

And using it in a try catch block in a BackgroundWorker thread

```
 private void _backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         _backup.Backup(_folders);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() => {  
             ErrorDialog.Show(this.XamlRoot, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);                  
         });
     }
 }
```

Comment: You can mark your answer. So that will be a guidance to others.